# Embedded Office Add-in in XML file - manifest location

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have developed a web add-in for Excel. For local development, I've simply sideloaded it as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac).

However, in the process of embedding the add-in in my excel file (using this tool [Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin)) I am running into a requirement of storing the manifest file on private server. Is it possible for embedded add-in to load its manifest from custom location ?

I'd like to avoid publishing the add-in to Office Store since it will only be used with my custom excel file which will be distributed to clients.

For context:

The add-in will be used only within the custom excel file by external clients.Upon downloading such excel file the client should be able to accept/trust my add in and begin using it.

Comment: See the [Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) section of the official docs for the various ways the manifest can be published. You probably want to use a Network Share or Centralized Deployment.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @RickKirkham.


Please correct me if I am mistaken but my understanding of Centralized Deployment is that it can be used to distribute an add-in to users in **my** organisation only ? It won't work for my external clients ?


Same for Network Share, the external clients would need to be in my network in order for my add-in to be accessible for them ?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you meant by "requirement of storing the manifest file on private server" or by "external clients". If you want to distribute the add-in to customers who are not in your org and do not have access to a common network share (and you don't want to use the store), then you would have to send a copy of the manifest to each customer and instruct them on how to put it on a Network Share in their LAN (and install it) or instruct them how to sideload it.

Comment: Also, see this blog post, which was published today by coincidence: https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/